# In php unit testing I'm getting an illegal string error, ErrorException: Illegal string offset 'tableData'

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

The controller and unit testController in laravel. and getting the error of illegal string of the 'tableData'which is defined to map the array of $arrViewBoundData

```
 public function getGroupList()
        {
            try {
                $requiredPermissions = [
                    config('permission.group_list_view_own'),
                    config('permission.group_list_view_all'),
                ];
                if (!$this->userPermissionHelper->checkHasPermissionFor($requiredPermissions)) {
                    return view('error.permission-denied');
                }
                $arrGroup = $this->groupRepo->getGroupList(Input::get());
                return view('group.index', $arrGroup);
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                return view('error.error_404');
            }
        }
    public function testGetGroupListForListOfRecords()
        {
            $this->app->instance('middleware.disable', true);
            $sampleJsonFile = file_get_contents(base_path('tests\Unit\sample_outputs\group_list.json'));
            $sampleOutput = json_decode($sampleJsonFile, true);

            $sampleOutput['tableData'] = array((object) $sampleOutput['tableData']);
            $sampleOutput['langList'] = array((object) $sampleOutput['langList']);
            $this->objMockGroupRepositoryInterface->shouldReceive('getGroupList')->andReturn($sampleOutput);
            $this->app->instance(GroupRepositoryInterface::class, $this->objMockGroupRepositoryInterface);
            $response = $this->call('GET', 'test-group/group');
            $arrViewBoundData = $response->original;
            $this->assertGreaterThan(0,count($arrViewBoundData['tableData']));
        }
```

Comment: Please show results of `dd($sampleOutput)` right after `$sampleOutput = json_decode($sampleJsonFile, true);`

Comment: PHPUnit 6.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

array:5 [
  "GroupId" => 26
  "GroupName" => "ABC"
  "Slug" => "ABC"
  "BelongsTo" => "ABC"
  "AssignedOrgernization" => "ABC"
]

Comment: The array doesn't have `tableData` that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: I can get you but I have defined tabledata in my sample output then why it's not considered

Comment: array:10 [
  "tableData" => array:5 [
    "GroupId" => 26
    "GroupName" => "ABC"
    "Slug" => "ABC"
    "BelongsTo" => "ABC"
    "AssignedOrgernization" => "ABC"
  ]
  "langList" => array:4 [
    "LanguageId" => 1
    "LanguageCode" => "EN"
    "IsDefault" => 1
    "IsActive" => 1
  ]
  "pageCount" => 3
  "currentPageNumber" => 3
  "sortType" => 3
  "sortTypeNext" => "asc"
  "sortByColumn" => "GroupName"
  "status" => 1
  "searchText" => null
  "langId" => 1
]

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin now I get this as output  for dd($sampleoutput) but still having the error of illegal string offset